# Automatic Increase in height (html, CSS)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry for the most uncreative title for this post but I don't know how to put this in words.

I created a DIV

```
<div class="pull-right" id="options">
    <ul class="list-inline text-right" >
        <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></button></li>
        <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-time"></button></li>
        <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></button></li>
        <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am using the following CSS to Hide and Show this DIV on Mouse-hover

```
<style>
    #options {
        display: none;
    }

    #itemcard:hover #options {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

It works fine but the issue is when I move my mouse to div class #itemcard it extends the high of the DIV

I hope I am explaining it well, here are some screenshots

[image: BEFORE MOUSE-HOVER]

*Before Mouse-Hover*

And now
[image]
*After Mouse-Hover*

As we can see the Buttons are displaying but it created a bigger GAP (Displayed with Redlines in the screenshot).

How can I not this happen and keep the hight consistent? I don't want to restrict the hight of the DIV as I will run it to more issue if the DIV has more data to show

Is it possible to render DIV to the size "BEFORE" the #options was turned to display:none ?

Cheers

Comment: There might be hover effects for the icons used there which slightly increases size as mouse moved over it & cause height difference. please check Im not sure, this may be a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to see the difference in height, then better use `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible` on mouse hover. `visibility: hidden` will keep the height of the div by default.

Answer (score 1):

There can be so many options to solve your issue. But the best, if you'll use `visibility:hidden/visible` instead of `display:none/block`.

Comment: hope i have written the same above!

Comment: Yes. Actually I was writing the same when you've already posted :).

Answer (score 0):

You must take a look to Inspector and check hovered height of div. Fixed height not nessesary mean that will be fixed. You not provided CSS so I can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
 - Reduce image size.
 - Remove extra border on image.
This might fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is replace `display: none;` with `visibility: hidden;` and `display: block;` with `visibility: visible;` This approach will keep the height of the `div` by default.

Here is a simple implementation.

```css
#options {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#itemcard:hover #options {
  visibility: visible;
}

ul.list-inline {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 260px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

li button {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="itemcard">
  Item Card 1
  <div id="options" class="pull-right">
    <ul class="list-inline text-right">
      <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-tags">1</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-time">2</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty">3</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger">4</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="itemcard">
  Item Card 2
  <div id="options" class="pull-right">
    <ul class="list-inline text-right">
      <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-tags">1</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-time">2</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty">3</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger">4</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```